# Taking sup of one variable of a continuous function of two variables produces a continuous function of the other variable

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(S,d)$ be a metric space, $F$ a closed set in $S$, and $f$ a continuous, bounded, nonnegative function on $F$. For $x\in S-F$, let $g(x):=\text{sup}_{t\in F}f(t)/(1+d(t,x)^2)^{1/d(x,F)}$. Prove $g$ is continuous on $S-F$.

My efforts:

$G(x,t)=f(t)/(1+d(t,x)^2)^{1/d(x,F)}$ is continuous about $x\in S-F$ for any fixed $t\in F$ and is continuous about $t\in F$ for any fixed $x\in S-F$. Given any $\epsilon>0$, we want to find a $\delta>0$ such that $|g(x)-g(y)|<\epsilon$ if $d(x,y)<\delta$. Suppose $g(x)=G(x,t_1)$ and $g(y)=G(y,t_2)$. Then $|g(x)-g(y)|\leq|G(x,t_1)-G(x,t)|+|G(x,t)-G(y,t)|+|G(y,t)-G(y,t_2)|$.

I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote

$$G(t,x)= \frac{f(t)}{(1+d(t,x)^2)^{\frac{1}{d(x,F)}}}$$
$G$ is continuous on $D=F\times S\setminus F$ as a composition of continuous maps ($x \mapsto d(x,F)$ is continuous).

$G$ is also bounded on $D$ by $\sup_{t \in F} f(t)$. Then it is a general result that $g$ is continuous.